404 error when fetching PDFs in my github repository
I pushed several PDFs in my github repository and found out that it was not rendering it in the UI.
The PDFs was not corrupted
When I was looking in the devtool>network I'm getting a 404 error when fetching the pdf here
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Bfault/Etudes/a6455f24ca2cc881b93015a3b950c3e7f683082a/L1/science_decision/2024-09-12-CM-1/2024-09-12-CM-1.pdf
[HTTP/2 404  184ms]
This is one of my PDFs
https://github.com/Bfault/Etudes/blob/master/L1/science_decision/2024-09-12-CM-1/2024-09-12-CM-1.pdf
I also found out that all my previously working PDFs are doing the same thing in all of my repository
But the thing is when I'm cloning the repository, every PDFs is fine

it seems your repository is not public

It's odd, in the setting it's says This repository is currently public.

its scares me, when I try to go on my github account from a private window I'm getting a 404 error

It's seems that my account has been flagged, made a ticket to know why.
I lost like 5hours on this...

It was a false positive, after a ticket I get unflagged
